# how to get keys of array of type dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift

how to get keys of array of type dictionary in swift. I want the output as 
    location1, location2, location3 (keys of data array of type dictionary)

// my code is given below

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController 
        {
        var data = [NSDictionary]()

            var LocationPickerData:[String] = ["Mozzarella","Gorgonzola","Provolone","Brie","Maytag Blue","Sharp Cheddar","Monterrey Jack","Stilton","Gouda","Goat Cheese", "Asiago"]

            var LocationPickerData2 = ["Mozzarella","Gorgonzola","Provolone","Brie","Maytag Blue","Sharp Cheddar","Monterrey Jack","Stilton","Gouda","Goat Cheese", "Asiago"]

            var LocationPickerData3 = ["Mozzarella","Gorgonzola","Provolone","Brie","Maytag Blue","Sharp Cheddar","Monterrey Jack","Stilton","Gouda","Goat Cheese", "Asiago"]

     override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
             data = [["lacation1":LocationPickerData],["location2":LocationPickerData2],["location2":LocationPickerData3]]

print(data[keys])

        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you will have to loop through `data` and in each iteration get a key of the first object in the array. That's because it is an `Array` of `Dictionaries`, not a `Dictionary`. However, I would recommend structuring your `data` variable as a `Dictionary`, there is really no reason not to unless there is something more to your solution.

I would suggest doing the following:

```
data = ["location1":LocationPickerData, "location2":LocationPickerData2, "location3":LocationPickerData3]
```

Then, it is trivial to get your keys:

```
data.keys
```

Note: `Dictionary` will not be sorted.